# $_SESSION variables don't get saved when automatically logged in

Tags: php, mysql, database, session-variables

I have an iPhone application that communicates with a database which includes things like users data (i.e. username, email, password), I created a PHP API for that and I connect to that API in the iPhone app. My problem here is: I save the user id in `$_SESSION` to restore it later when needed, when I manually log in, `$_SESSION` variables get saved easily and I can call them whenever I want, but when the app automatically logs in (which is obviously after the first log in where username and password get store in the iPhone keychain), `$_SESSION` variables doesn't get saved, I noticed that they only get stored and called with no problems after I log out which translates to after `session_destroy();`, here's the php code I use for logging in and out

```
session_start();

function login($user, $pass) {

    $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

    if (count($result['result'])>0) {

        $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

        print json_encode($result);

    } else {
        errorJson('Authorization failed');
    }
}

function logout() {

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}
```

I tried to add `session_destroy();` at the start of login method, but it didn't work.

By the way, I can alternatively save `IdUser` in `NSUserDefaults` or iPhone keychain and send it to the server when needed. [Is it safe/not wrong to do such things on the app side rather than the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868780/is-it-safe-to-do-certain-things-on-local-side-rather-than-server-side)

Comment: I don't really get your question .. Are you sure session works with your app and cookie or something else wouldn't be better?

Comment: I am sure it works, I know this is strange somehow. But probably it could be me missing something. BTW, if I called `logout` in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and called `login` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` it works (for sure, after I close the app while it's in the background and open it again), but only for this time, when I re-open the app it doesn't work.

Comment: Is ``session_start()`` being called at the very first line in the PHP file (before anything is outputted)?

Comment: Your SQL statement suggests that you're using saving your password in plaintext. That's not true, right?

Comment: @kba No, that's right. I created this database with the intention of gaining new skills and testing.

Comment: @Abd-ElrhmanRizk Don't ever ever do that. Please read [PHP: Safe Password Hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: Is the iPhone apo sending the cookie with session id?

Answer (score 0):

Try the logout function like this ...

```
function logout() {
session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: `session_start()` is **already invoked** by the time `logout()` is called. It won't change anything

Comment: I guess The problem is that when you are calling the function session_start() is not getting invoked please try session_start() inside the logout and login function.

Comment: I'm not the OP. And your guess is just wrong. It's not possible

Comment: what do you mean by I'm not the OP

Comment: it's not me who asked a question :-) OP == original poster

Comment: As @zerkms said, it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the logout function like this

function logout() {

```
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
```

}

1. When you call the logout function,it doesn't call the session_start(),so you can't get the the session variables.You should get it before you will edit it.
2. Detail:[php.net session_destory()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)